# Insert json data from pandas to MySQL with pymysql

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, pymysql

I have a csv file with columns which are json dumped lists or dict.

Example entry of `pictures` column  `["https://images1.loopnet.com/i2/-zlV--gguqB1DTY1kXtod7Y11T6NjYHuEOsdziUbkIc/110/106-Caines-St-Seward-AK-Primary-Photo-1-Large.jpg", "https://images1.loopnet.com/i2/9oRXPv2oL67ts0OBDiQq--j6wl2NaP2_fVpRG4WmPWs/110/106-Caines-St-Seward-AK-Interior-Photo-2-Large.jpg", "https://images1.loopnet.com/i2/Whv9igp7CuqG14CkzA5y6oHo7NA0mltLBMttvdhTd1Y/110/106-Caines-St-Seward-AK-Interior-Photo-3-Large.jpg", "https://images1.loopnet.com/i2/WmAM3YCIRbr7NtaP322I98DjvqGY7MMf_p8fyKsZhVs/110/106-Caines-St-Seward-AK-Interior-Photo-4-Large.jpg", "https://images1.loopnet.com/i2/dB7SmPhSBDinpHJOM5oRxg6sLSF7Bp_Pa5SdyeCQpl0/110/106-Caines-St-Seward-AK-Interior-Photo-5-Large.jpg"]`

Example of `financial_info` column `{"Gross Rental Income": {"annual": null, "annual_per_sf": null}, "Other Income": {"annual": null, "annual_per_sf": null}, "Vacancy Loss": {"annual": null, "annual_per_sf": null}, "Effective Gross Income": {"annual": null, "annual_per_sf": null}, "Net Operating Income": {"annual": 99999.0, "annual_per_sf": 9.99}}`

I want to load it from csv to pandas data frame and insert it to MySQL database. I have those columns in MySQL defined as json type.

But I get `pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'["https://images1.loo...`

I thought it is problem with encoding or quotes but it is not working when I applied

```
import pandas as pd
from pymysql.converters import escape_string

data = pd.read_csv(filename, encoding="utf-8")
data["pictures"] = data["pictures"].apply(escape_string)

load_data_to_db(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

In this code, we use pd.json.dumps to convert the JSON data in the DataFrame to a JSON-formatted string. Then, when inserting the data into the MySQL database, we use %s as placeholders for the JSON-formatted strings to avoid any SQL injection issues.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import pymysql

data = pd.read_csv(filename, encoding="utf-8")

data["pictures"] = data["pictures"].apply(pd.json.dumps)
data["financial_info"] = data["financial_info"].apply(pd.json.dumps)

cursor = connection.cursor()

for index, row in data.iterrows():
    sql = "INSERT INTO your_table (pictures, financial_info) VALUES (%s, %s)"
    values = (row["pictures"], row["financial_info"])
    cursor.execute(sql, values)
```

Sample code from JSON-formatted strings back to JSON data:

```
import json

json_str = '{"key": "value", "numbers": [1, 2, 3], "nested": {"foo": "bar"}}'
json_data = json.loads(json_str)
print(json_data)

print(json_data["key"])  # output: 'value'
print(json_data["numbers"])  # output: [1, 2, 3]
```